# Store the employee name in the report table or just the employee number that references an associative table?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a web application for internal use. One of the main features is the ability for the users to enter Sales Call Reports. My question is simply: Do I store the Employee Name and Company Name in the Call Reports table or do I only store the employee number and customer number in the table, as foreign keys and then retrieve the Employee Name and Customer Name, using the foreign keys, for display purposes? It seems like the foreign keys option would be procedural correct, however, it would be much easier to retrieve data from only 1 table when displaying the call reports.

Comment: personally i would use foreign keys because then you don't have Employee Name and Customer Name stored in multiple places, like what if Employee Name is changed or Customer Name changes or updated due to initial errors. But it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I know that the question seems subjective but I also know there are accepted best practices. Tin Tran, thank you for mentioning about not having the same data in 2 places, that is a good best practice and lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'll save future-you a lot of pain by storing them separately as you've described.

On the face of it, and initially it seems like lots of extra work, but you'll end up with a much more flexible system, and 2 JOINS in a query isn't a lot.